# Optimize hollow diamond pattern printing in c with minimum loops

Tags: c, performance, loops, design-patterns

Am trying to print hollow diamond pattern with * outline with minimum loops. I optimized with 2 loops.

My output using 2 loops

```
Enter no of rows: 5
***********
***** *****
****   ****
***     ***
**       **
*         *
**       **
***     ***
****   ****
***** *****
***********
```

Is there any other way to still optimize this code?

```
void main()
{
        int row,col,n,k;

        printf("Enter no of rows: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        for(row=0, k=1; row<=2*n; row>n?k++:k, printf("\n"), row++)
                for(col=-n; col<=n; col++)
                        (col>0?col:-col) < (row<=n?row:(row-2*k)) ? printf(" ") : printf("*");
}
```

'

Comment: Does "minimum loops" mean "the minimum number of loops", or something else? And perhaps this question would be better suited for the "Programming Puzzles & Code Golf" site?

Comment: By "optimize" do you mean take less time? If not, ignore this comment. If so, do you understand that `printf` takes orders of magnitude more time than anything else you've got here? And do you understand that loops are not inherently slow just because they may be conceptually complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save a lot of time by figuring out that `(row<=n?row:(row-2*k))` doesn't depend on the inner loop variable

So writing that:

```
int row,col,n,k;

printf("Enter no of rows: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

for(row=0, k=1; row<=2*n; row>n?k++:k, putchar('\n'), row++)
{
    int z=(row<=n?row:(row-2*k));
    for(col=-n; col<=n; col++)
        putchar((col>0?col:-col) < z ? ' ' : '*');
}
```

is equivalent, but you have a lot less tests (note the better way to use ternary expression inside printf rather than 2 printfs).

(also replaced bloated `printf` by `putchar` which is fine here, and probably faster)